# How to parse Json data by chunks in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous

I'm creating a REST API that gets raw data from the internet then apply a REGEX to it and return it in JSON format.

this is my function for getting Data as JSON.
first i'm using got() to get the raw data than I apply ANIME_LIST_REGEX.exec() to filter it with the regular expression to make it in JSON format.

```
async function getAnimeList(url) {
const {body} = await got(url);

let ANIME_LIST_DATA = ANIME_LIST_REGEX.exec(body)

if (!ANIME_LIST_DATA) {
    return null;
}

return {
    animeList: ANIME_LIST_DATA[1]
};
```

}

in this endpoint I'm retreiving the data from the 1st function and parsing the JSON, the return it as a response.

```
app.get('/anime-list', async (req, res, next) => {
    const appData = await getAnimeList(URL_BASE_ANIME_LIST);
    var listJson = JSON5.parse(appData.animeList)
    res.json(listJson)
})
```

The issue is that the returned array is pretty big (5000 entries of js objects) and the request takes long time to return and show the array
What I want to do is to return a chunck of that array every time I call the function or reach the endpoint.
Tried several methods but none of them made sense.
Does anyone got an idea?

Comment: Do you need JSON5, or is it actually just JSON?

Comment: I would recommend not to parse and re-stringify the JSON text at all. Just send the `appData` string directly, only make sure to set the content-type header like `res.json` does it.

Comment: call getAnimeList once not per request

Comment: @Bergi : yes I could do that.
But my problem is that the returned array as a large one and it takes alot to return the response.
I want to know if there's a way to get only a part of that data every time I call a function ( every time I press a button it loads more data and not the whole data for example )

Comment: That would depend on whether your `getAnimeList` function and especially the API from which you are getting the data yourself does support that. But yes, it is possible in general, it's called "pagination".

Answer (score 0):

You can split the large array into a small chunk with [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). To determine the range of the chunk, you can pass queries to the endpoint.

```js
app.get("/anime-list", async (req, res, next) => {
  const appData = await getAnimeList(URL_BASE_ANIME_LIST)
  var listJson = JSON5.parse(appData.animeList)

  const from = req.query.from || 0
  const count = req.query.count || 100
  res.json(listJson.splice(from, count))
})
```

However, as others mention, calling `getAnimeList()` per request will cause another performance problem. I highly suggest you refactor the function to cache the result.

Comment: I think you meant `slice`. `splice` mutates the array, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yes I think I need to cache the result for futur requests, the issue is that the first user that will request the data ( when the cache is not filled yet ) will have to wait alot.
I don't know if I can implement like a periodic caching where the program runs the function itself and fill the cache ( + keep it up to date).